# Earliest time of daily maximum values

Tags: mysql

I have a table that logs weather data variables by datetime like this:

```
|------------------|------------| ----
| LogDateTime      | Temp       | ...
+------------------|------------| ----
| 2020-01-01 00:00 | 20.1       | ...                                  
| 2020-01-01 00:05 | 20.1       | ...                                  
| 2020-01-01 00:10 | 19.9       | ...                                  
| 2020-01-01 00:15 | 19.8       | ...                                  
---------------------------------------
```

From that table I want to return the earliest time of the maximum temperature for each day like this (just the time portion of the datetime value):

```
|------------|----------------------
| LogDate    | LogTime|  MaxTemp
+---------------------|--------------
| 2020-01-01 |  14:00 |   24.5                                     
| 2020-01-02 |  15:12 |   23.2                                 
| 2020-01-03 |  10:12 |   25.1                                   
| 2020-01-04 |  12:14 |   28.8                                   
--------------------------------
```

The query I have to return this so far is the below, but it returns the earliest temperature for each day instead of the earliest occurrence of the maximum temperature for each day

```
    SELECT TIME(a.LogDateTime), a.Temp
FROM Monthly a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TIME(LogDateTime), LogDateTime, MAX(Temp) Temp
    FROM Monthly
    GROUP BY LogDateTime
) b ON a.LogDateTime = b.LogDateTime AND a.Temp= b.Temp
GROUP BY DATE(a.LogDateTime)
```

I then want to use that query to update a table of one row per day that summarises the minimum and maximum values with a query something like this but update the time rather than the actual maximum temperature:

```
        UPDATE Dayfile AS d
JOIN (
    SELECT DATE(LogDateTime) AS date, MAX(Temp) AS Temps
    FROM Monthly
    GROUP BY date
) AS m ON DATE(d.LogDate) = m.date
SET d.MaxTemp = m.Temps
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a single `MaxTemp` per day? Your expected result shows the same day with four max temps...

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv8l)

Comment: @The Impaler: my bad, yes there should be only 1 max per day. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of MariaDB supports window functions, so use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select LogDateTime, Temp
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by date(LogDateTime) order by Temp desc, LogDateTime) rn
  from Monthly
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ff8422c6c58d2111e203c8b49f482a8a).

Use it to update `Dayfile` like this:

```
update Dayfile d
inner join (
  select LogDateTime, Temp
  from (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by date(LogDateTime) order by Temp desc, LogDateTime) rn
    from Monthly
  ) t
  where t.rn = 1
) m on date(d.LogDate) = m.date
set d.MaxTemp = m.Temp
```